# Bring attributes from many rows into one row together

Tags: sql

I have a cte with some case when statements. The output is the ID and some columns like

```
ID  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2...
```

My desired output is

```
ID  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0
2...
```

I have tryed it with a distinct on my cte and again some case when statements, but i dont get it to that point, that just one row per ID is the result.

Comment: What if there is a row with `id = 1` and `C1 = 42` which value would you want to see then?

Comment: Just have 1 or 0 so your answer helped, thxs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care *which* row you pick per ID, just do a max() on each column:

```sql
select id, 
       max(c1) as c1, 
       max(c2) as c2, 
       max(c3) as c3, 
       max(c4) as c4, 
       max(c5) as c5, 
       max(c6) as c6, 
       max(c7) as c7, 
       max(c8) as c8
from the_table
group by id
order by id;
```